# Octave Script Creating Symbolic Function from?

Tags: debugging, warnings, octave

I'm trying to calculate the following using a nested for loop. Inputs to the equation are either real positive doubles, or arrays with real positive doubles within them. there are no symbolic inputs. Earlier in the code, I use symbolic variables, but I convert them into doubles by doing "double(x)", for instance.

When the equation runs within this particular script file, it errors out saying trying to pass floating points to syms is dangerous, so on and so forth.

When I open up a new tab, and hard code the variables with doubles, and run the script, and look at the output of the equation, it runs fine and I'm able to plot what I need to...

I can't figure out why within the main script I've written, the equation is turning every result into a symbolic answer, and ultimately creating a symbolic matrix...

I know this script works because it was working before, so the origin was a working script.

The code equation looks like below:

```
fo_act = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(Lr_chosen*Cr_chosen))

fmin = double(Min_Norm_freq)*fo

fmax = double(Max_Norm_freq)*fo

FN_plot  = [0.1:0.001:fmax/fo*1.5]

QE_plot  = [0; Qe_minimum_load_value; Qe_act; Qe_ovrld_act]

LN_act = 3.5;

topology_Constant = 1;

for i = 1:size(QE_plot,1)
  for q = 1:size(FN_plot,2)
    MG(i,q) = (((LN_act*FN_plot(q)^2))/((((LN_act+1)*(FN_plot(q).^2)-1)+j*(((FN_plot(q)^2)-1).*FN_plot(q).*QE_plot(i)*LN_act))))*1/topology_Constant;
  endfor
endfor
```

Within the command window, when I get the answer for each variable before the for loops, they show up as real doubles.

I added an image, showing that Fn_plot is a double, and all the other variables are real doubles or integers as I stated. Also, showing the warning I'm getting.

[Scirpt Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj8iM.png)

That type of error will go forever unless you ctrl + C to stop it.

When I do ctrl + C, and then print the output of the function, I get the output below:

[MG function Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idJmG.png)

To add to this, I copy and pasted the code into a new script page. But, to this page before the nested for loop I hardcode the values as shown below. So, nothing above this really matters because the as you can see the equation is just using values I hardcoded manually, and nothing above.

You can't run this because you need other functions that are other files. This is the code, though.

```
clear all;
clc;
pkg 

   x = input('For Max Gain Max load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for MG : ' );

    y = input('For Max Gain Max load,Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for QE : ' );

    z = input('For Max Gain Max load,Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 10) for LN : ' );




%Select QE, MG, LN, for Max_gain -> minimum frequency
MG = sym(x)/100;
QE_maxLoad = sym(y)/100;
LN = sym(z)/10;
Des_rev = 0;
topology_Constant = 1;

Mg_Min = 0.79586;
Mg_max_ov = 1.2706;

Attainable_Peak_Gain_Graph(Mg_max_ov,Mg_Min,LN, Des_rev, topology_Constant)
printf(newline)
x0 = input('Enter Decimal Value for initial Guess for Numaerical Solver : ' );
printf(newline)
Min_Norm_freq = Fn_calc(MG, QE_maxLoad, LN, x0)
printf(newline)






#{

    x = input('For Minimum Gain Minimum load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for MG : ' );

    y = input('For Minimum Gain Minimum Load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for QE : ' );

    x0 = input('Enter Decimal Value for initial Guess for Numaerical Solver : ' );

MG = sym(x)/100;
QE_min_load = sym(y)/100;
printf(newline)
Max_Norm_freq = Fn_calc(MG, QE_min_load, LN, x0)
#}


printf(newline)
printf(newline)

n_act = 4;
Vout_nom = 42;
Iout = 56;

%Determine Re
Re = ((8 * n_act^2)/pi^2)*(Vout_nom/Iout) % Full load Re
Re_overLoad = Re/1.1 % Over load Re @ 110%

%Determine Resonant Components

MG = double(MG);
QE = double(QE_maxLoad)
LN = double(LN)

%Initial Chosen Resonant Frequency, 90% of Fmax

fo = input('Enter The Resonant Frequency of choice: ' )
printf(newline)

QE_CR = QE;

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Resonant Capacitance')
printf(newline)

Cr = 1/(2*pi*fo*Re*QE_CR)

Cr_chosen = input('Enter Chosen Value for Cr : ' )

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Resonant Inductances and Normalized Inductance')
printf(newline)
Lr = 1/(((2*pi*fo)^2)*Cr_chosen)
printf(newline)
Lr_actual = (QE_CR*Re)^2 * Cr_chosen
%Qe_Cr_Chosen = sqrt(Lr/Cr_chosen)/Re
printf(newline)
Lr_chosen = input('Enter Chosen Value for Lr : ' )
Lm_required_for_Chosen_LN = LN*Lr_chosen
LM_chosen = input('Enter Chosen Value for LM : ' )
LN_act = LM_chosen/Lr_chosen


%Verify Design and Produce Gain graph



printf(newline)
printf(newline)

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Full load and Overload Q factors')
printf(newline)

%Quality Factor at Full load
Qe_act = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/Re

%Quality Factor at Overload
Qe_ovrld_act = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/Re_overLoad

 printf(newline)
 printf(newline)



% Finding Max Normalized frequency for Minimum Load

% Finding Max Normalized frequency for Minimum Load

    pout = input('Enter the minimum output load in watts : ' );

   % y  = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/((8 * n_act^2)/pi^2)*(Vout_nom^2/pout); % QE_min_load
    printf(newline)
    Qe_minimum_load_value = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/(((8 * n_act^2)/pi^2)*(Vout_nom^2/pout))
    printf(newline)
    Mg_Min
    x = input('For Minimum Gain Minimum load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for MG : ' );

    y = input('Knowing Qe_minimum_load_value above, Enter the value (knowing it will be divided by 1000) for QE : ' );

    x0 = input('Enter Decimal Value for initial Guess for Numaerical Solver : ' );

MG = sym(x)/100;
QE_min_load = sym(y)/1000;
printf(newline)
Max_Norm_freq = Fn_calc(MG, QE_min_load, LN, x0)

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Design Frequencies')
printf(newline)
fo_act = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(Lr_chosen*Cr_chosen))
%fmin = double(Min_Norm_freq)*fo
fmin = 80000;
fmax = 250000;
%fmax = double(Max_Norm_freq)*fo
%FN_plot = [0.1:0.001:double(Max_Norm_freq)*1.5];
FN_plot  = [0.1:0.001:3];
%QE_plot = [0; double(QE_min_load); Qe_act; Qe_ovrld_act];
QE_plot  = [0; 0.35; 0.549; 0.60449];

for i = 1:size(QE_plot,1)
  for q = 1:size(FN_plot,2)
    MG(i,q) = (((3*FN_plot(q)^2))/((((3+1)*(FN_plot(q).^2)-1)+j*(((FN_plot(q)^2)-1).*FN_plot(q).*QE_plot(i)*3))))*1/1;
  endfor
endfor

%{
QE_plot = {0,"No Load"; Qe_minimum_load_value, "Min Load"; Qe_act, "Full Load"; Qe_ovrld_act, "Overload"};


figure()
%plot(FN_plot,abs(MG), 'MarkerSize', 10, 'LineWidth', 1.25, 'DisplayName', 'No load', 'DisplayName', 'Full Load', 'DisplayName', 'Overload')
plot(FN_plot,abs(MG), 'MarkerSize', 10, 'LineWidth', 1.25)

hold on
%semilogx(F_POS,F_cap_Q,'m','LineWidth', 1);
%semilogx(F_POS,F_cap_Q,'ro','LineWidth', 1,'MarkerSize', 5);
%title(['Design Rev ', num2str(Des_rev), " - MG_a_c_t_u_a_l vs F_n"] , 'fontsize', 25)

xlabel(" F_n (Normalized Frequency)",'fontsize', 24)
ylabel(" MG_a_c_t_u_a_l", 'fontsize', 24)
axis ([0, fmax/fo*1.4 , 0.6*0.79, 1.3*1.5])
```

I then write the exact same code except I remove all the code above "fmin", with the hardcoded values into another new script page, it runs fine. Just to show it's the exact same, the image below.. I don't see how this makes any sense.

```
fmin = 80000;
fmax = 250000;
%fmax = double(Max_Norm_freq)*fo
%FN_plot = [0.1:0.001:double(Max_Norm_freq)*1.5];
FN_plot  = [0.1:0.001:3];
%QE_plot = [0; double(QE_min_load); Qe_act; Qe_ovrld_act];
QE_plot  = [0; 0.35; 0.549; 0.60449];

for i = 1:size(QE_plot,1)
  for q = 1:size(FN_plot,2)
    MG(i,q) = (((3*FN_plot(q)^2))/((((3+1)*(FN_plot(q).^2)-1)+j*(((FN_plot(q)^2)-1).*FN_plot(q).*QE_plot(i)*3))))*1/1;
  endfor
endfor
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782). Copy-paste the code and the output into the question. Also make sure you post a [mre], and run that script in a freshly started Octave session to verify it actually reproduces the problem (earlier commands might affect what happens, we need to make sure we see exactly the same thing you see when we run your scripts).

Comment: I've done as you've asked, but you can not reproduce it because you need other files that are functions. You can see the code as is though, and hopefully understand it from there. I have already tried restarting Octave and running again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer last night, I put a ton of percentage signs where the variable MG is assigned the symbolic class. The code worked previously because I reused the same variable (MG) twice, but, before going to that main equation I made it a double. When I moved bits and pieces of my code around, I forgot to assign it a double before heading into that equation, hence the problem I was having...

```
clear all;
clc;
pkg 

   x = input('For Max Gain Max load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for MG : ' );

    y = input('For Max Gain Max load,Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for QE : ' );

    z = input('For Max Gain Max load,Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 10) for LN : ' );




%Select QE, MG, LN, for Max_gain -> minimum frequency

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
MG = sym(x)/100;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

QE_maxLoad = sym(y)/100;
LN = sym(z)/10;
Des_rev = 0;
topology_Constant = 1;

Mg_Min = 0.79586;
Mg_max_ov = 1.2706;

Attainable_Peak_Gain_Graph(Mg_max_ov,Mg_Min,LN, Des_rev, topology_Constant)
printf(newline)
x0 = input('Enter Decimal Value for initial Guess for Numaerical Solver : ' );
printf(newline)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Min_Norm_freq = Fn_calc(MG, QE_maxLoad, LN, x0)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

printf(newline)







#{

    x = input('For Minimum Gain Minimum load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for MG : ' );

    y = input('For Minimum Gain Minimum Load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for QE : ' );

    x0 = input('Enter Decimal Value for initial Guess for Numaerical Solver : ' );
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
**MG** = sym(x)/100;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
QE_min_load = sym(y)/100;
printf(newline)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Max_Norm_freq = Fn_calc(**MG**, QE_min_load, LN, x0)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#}


printf(newline)
printf(newline)

n_act = 4;
Vout_nom = 42;
Iout = 56;

%Determine Re
Re = ((8 * n_act^2)/pi^2)*(Vout_nom/Iout) % Full load Re
Re_overLoad = Re/1.1 % Over load Re @ 110%

%Determine Resonant Components

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
MG = double(MG);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

QE = double(QE_maxLoad)
LN = double(LN)

%Initial Chosen Resonant Frequency, 90% of Fmax

fo = input('Enter The Resonant Frequency of choice: ' )
printf(newline)

QE_CR = QE;

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Resonant Capacitance')
printf(newline)

Cr = 1/(2*pi*fo*Re*QE_CR)

Cr_chosen = input('Enter Chosen Value for Cr : ' )

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Resonant Inductances and Normalized Inductance')
printf(newline)
Lr = 1/(((2*pi*fo)^2)*Cr_chosen)
printf(newline)
Lr_actual = (QE_CR*Re)^2 * Cr_chosen
%Qe_Cr_Chosen = sqrt(Lr/Cr_chosen)/Re
printf(newline)
Lr_chosen = input('Enter Chosen Value for Lr : ' )
Lm_required_for_Chosen_LN = LN*Lr_chosen
LM_chosen = input('Enter Chosen Value for LM : ' )
LN_act = LM_chosen/Lr_chosen


%Verify Design and Produce Gain graph



printf(newline)
printf(newline)

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Full load and Overload Q factors')
printf(newline)

%Quality Factor at Full load
Qe_act = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/Re

%Quality Factor at Overload
Qe_ovrld_act = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/Re_overLoad

 printf(newline)
 printf(newline)



% Finding Max Normalized frequency for Minimum Load

% Finding Max Normalized frequency for Minimum Load

    pout = input('Enter the minimum output load in watts : ' );

   % y  = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/((8 * n_act^2)/pi^2)*(Vout_nom^2/pout); % QE_min_load
    printf(newline)
    Qe_minimum_load_value = sqrt(Lr_chosen/Cr_chosen)/(((8 * n_act^2)/pi^2)*(Vout_nom^2/pout))
    printf(newline)
    Mg_Min
    x = input('For Minimum Gain Minimum load, Enter a value (knowing it will be divided by 100) for MG : ' );

    y = input('Knowing Qe_minimum_load_value above, Enter the value (knowing it will be divided by 1000) for QE : ' );

    x0 = input('Enter Decimal Value for initial Guess for Numaerical Solver : ' );
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
MG = sym(x)/100;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


QE_min_load = sym(y)/1000;
printf(newline)
Max_Norm_freq = Fn_calc(MG, QE_min_load, LN, x0)

printf(newline)
printf(newline)
printf('Design Frequencies')
printf(newline)
fo_act = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(Lr_chosen*Cr_chosen))
%fmin = double(Min_Norm_freq)*fo
fmin = 80000;
fmax = 250000;
%fmax = double(Max_Norm_freq)*fo
%FN_plot = [0.1:0.001:double(Max_Norm_freq)*1.5];
FN_plot  = [0.1:0.001:3];
%QE_plot = [0; double(QE_min_load); Qe_act; Qe_ovrld_act];
QE_plot  = [0; 0.35; 0.549; 0.60449];

for i = 1:size(QE_plot,1)
  for q = 1:size(FN_plot,2)
    MG(i,q) = (((3*FN_plot(q)^2))/((((3+1)*(FN_plot(q).^2)-1)+j*(((FN_plot(q)^2)-1).*FN_plot(q).*QE_plot(i)*3))))*1/1;
  endfor
endfor

%{
QE_plot = {0,"No Load"; Qe_minimum_load_value, "Min Load"; Qe_act, "Full Load"; Qe_ovrld_act, "Overload"};


figure()
%plot(FN_plot,abs(MG), 'MarkerSize', 10, 'LineWidth', 1.25, 'DisplayName', 'No load', 'DisplayName', 'Full Load', 'DisplayName', 'Overload')
plot(FN_plot,abs(MG), 'MarkerSize', 10, 'LineWidth', 1.25)

hold on
%semilogx(F_POS,F_cap_Q,'m','LineWidth', 1);
%semilogx(F_POS,F_cap_Q,'ro','LineWidth', 1,'MarkerSize', 5);
%title(['Design Rev ', num2str(Des_rev), " - MG_a_c_t_u_a_l vs F_n"] , 'fontsize', 25)

xlabel(" F_n (Normalized Frequency)",'fontsize', 24)
ylabel(" MG_a_c_t_u_a_l", 'fontsize', 24)
axis ([0, fmax/fo*1.4 , 0.6*0.79, 1.3*1.5])
```